# Detect when a range is not provided to a custom Ex command

Tags: vim

I have an Ex command that works differently based on whether a range was specified or not. I'd like to find out which variant of the command was used to alter it's behaviour.

My Command definition is,

`:command! -range Foo :call DoFoo(<line1>, <line2>)`

Currently I am getting `<line1>` and `<line2>` as the same line number, when I use it without a range like `:Foo`. Thus I can detect when a range is provided, ie:- when line numbers are different.

> I'd like to likewise detect when a range is not given.
>
> Is there a vim variable/option to do this. I am thinking something similar to the how the completer function has a `CmdLine` argument that indicates the entire line of the Ex command to the complete function.

Comment: say your cursor at line5, are `:Foo` and `:5 Foo` same for you?

Comment: Not exactly. I'd like to differentiate between a range of the lines selected vs No lines selected. Count isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, what should work, is to check the <count> variable.

```
:command! -range Foo :call DoFoo(<line1>, <line2>, <count>)
```

If no range is given, the count variable will be -1, else it will equal the second entered adress (or the first, if only a single line was given).

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you want to get the command line user has inputted, you could check the register `:`

in your script, it would be `@:`, read it to get the last command user inputted. You can in your function save it to a variable, if you want to change or do something else.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, but Thanks for your answer.